# Hide attributes based on previous selection

Tags: plugins, filters, widgets

I've been trying to achieve this on my shop page but I am not able to. Basically I have 3 attributes, brand, model, year. I want to hide specific attributes or disable them ( make them not selectable ) if there are no matching options. For example: I have 3 brands: Yamaha, Honda, Suzuki. I want when the Yamaha brand is selected to show only the models available for the Yamaha brand not all the models which are available for Honda Suzuki etc.. is this even possible with Woo? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is down to the way you build out your attributes and variations.  You have a BRAND attribute with Suzuki, Honda, Kawasaki.  Then you have a MODEL attribute with GSX 600, GSX 750, CBR 600, CBR 900, Ninja 750, Ninja 1100.  When you make variations you make Suzuki & GSX 600, Suzuki & GSX 750, then Honda & CBR 600, Honda & CBR 900, Kawasaki & Ninja 750 and lastly Kawasaki & Ninja 1100.  That would give you 6 variations from 2 attributes.  You can't buy a Kawasaki GSX, b/c that's not a thing, so you don't make that a variation.